# How to get maximum continuous iteration

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below and I need to get maximum continuous iterations for the individual drink.

[image]

The output should be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below - **[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=97ee8a8aaeb86862f1b725c8163a9c75)** Here

```
with cte as (
select drink,count(*) as cnt
from
(
select *,row_number() over(order by queue) -
row_number() over(partition by drink order by queue) as grp
from t
)A group by drink,grp )

select drink, max(cnt) from cte group by drink
```

Comment: queue is not dependable for ORDER BY, p1 is followed by p10.